# XBOX 360 - LEGO Dynamic Split-Screen Requirements

Tags: xbox-360

### What it is?

I first saw it on some *XBOX 360* version of *Indiana Jones* or something, but how it basically works is you share one screen for the two players, but as soon as the distance becomes too large between the two players, it starts to split. This is done seamlessly and is really convenient.

### My Question(s):

Does the size of the screen that is being used have an effect on this?
Are there any other requirements for this to work properly?

Comment: List answers and shopping recommendations are offtopic I am afraid.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness This question is more aimed at the Requirements, but will amend my question.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your title as well.  That said, I don't believe any game knows how large a TV you're playing it on, and therefore can't use anything related to that to change how it works.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? It's supported in the games it's supported in. Saying `I saw this feature in X *or something*, and it was cool. Does Y affect this?` doesn't give a clear question or an idea of what you're actually trying to achieve. Now you've removed the game-rec part from your question there just **doesn't seem to be a question to be answered.**

Comment: @TZHX I want to know what is needed for the feature to work. Whether it be a big screen, internet connection, a pizza or ice-cream, whatever (I know these are not necessarily correct). I want to know what is needed to have this feature in working order, and if there is anything that will stop this feature from functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the screen does not matter (the game has no way of knowing this).

The state of your Internet connection doesn't matter.

The presence or absence of any food products does not matter (although pouring ice cream on your Xbox will probably lead to the machine not working).

The only thing that matters is *whether the game has this feature*. The first LEGO game to feature it came out in November 2009.

Comment: `The first LEGO game to feature it came out in November 2009` - That makes sense, but is sad though. Other than that feature not being present, it is a great game, released in October 2009.